# XSD: change minOccurs of inside element depending on value of the attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this element in xsd.

```
        <xs:element name="OuterElement">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="InnerElement">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>

                <xs:attribute name="enabled" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

Is it possible to format the xsd in a way where the following would be possible? ...

```
if enabled==true {
   minOccursOfInnerElement=1
}
else {
   minOccursOfInnerElement=0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. an xsd defines the structure of the markup, the value of an attribute is what is marked up.

you could maybe do a choice element with one member for disabled and one for enabled.

Comment: Yes your suggestion is what I think is the right approach for me. But can there be two elements with the same name? Maybe the ref attribute would solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure to be honest, but if not, have a parent element with your common name and then a choice which will deliver one of two children

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to look at it is this:  you have two kinds of parent.  Enabled parents are required to have at least one inner-element child, while non-enabled parents are not required to have at least one.   The problem is trivial if you give them different names, and it becomes hard only if you decide that it's more important to you to use the same name for two different things than to have a simple approach to validation.

Comment: It has to be for the same names. That's why the attribute is there. Moreover, I can't change it. I'm making a schema for an existing program.

Comment: Then your task, if you serve the true and the good, is to go find the programmer who designed the format, and the manager who decreed it cannot be changed, and drive stakes through their hearts.